# How to configure Google Cloud Scheduler to run daily every 4 hours from 8 am to 8 pm?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I need help in configuring my Google Cloud Scheduler. I need the scheduler to run daily every 4 hours starting from 8 am to 8 pm. Can anyone please help me figure out how to achieve this frequency?

Comment: Read the documentation please, it's clearly explained there.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart there you can find a quickstart guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
0 8,12,16,20 * * *
```

Run at

- 8.00 am
- 12.00 pm
- 4.00 pm
- 8.00 pm